# change flash input textbox background color?

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs3

could some one tell me how to change flash input textbox background color? the standard color is white. i need to change it.

Answer (score 2):

See the [TextField](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html) docs: set `background` to true and set `backgroundColor` to the color you want.